# Speed Up the Updating of the Status Bar in Delphi

Tags: delphi, optimization, statusbar

Updating the status bar in Delphi takes so darn long!

Example: I search for files and display the number of files found and searched in the status bar:

```
OwnerForm.StatusBar1.SimpleText
     := Format('Searching (%d found in %d files) ...', [NumFound, Total]);
```

This adds approximately 1 second of time to the search for every 200 times the status bar is updated.

Are there any ways to reduce this excessive overhead, but still update the status for the user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't update your status bar this fast. How will a user be able to read the status if you update it so often that it has a serious impact on your performance?

Besides I ran a little test that shows it updates the status bar a 1000 times in just over 100 ms. This is on my 5 years old cheap home pc.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  a: Cardinal;
begin
  a := GetTickCount;
  for i := 0 to 1000 do
  begin
    StatusBar1.SimpleText := IntToStr(i);
  end;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetTickCount - a));
end;
```

[edit]

Alternative solution:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FLastUpdate: TDateTime;
  public
    procedure UpdateStatus(Status: string);
    procedure ForceStatus(Status: string);
  end;

procedure TForm1.ForceStatus(Status: string);
begin
  StatusBar1.SimpleText := Status;
  FLastUpdate := Now;
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateStatus(Status: string);
begin
  if MilliSecondsBetween(Now, FLastUpdate) > 500 then
  begin
    StatusBar1.SimpleText := Status;

    FLastUpdate := Now;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  a: Cardinal;
begin
  a := GetTickCount;
  for i := 0 to 1000000 do
  begin
    // unimportant: progress
    UpdateStatus(IntToStr(i));
  end;
  // Important: final state
  ForceStatus(Format('Done in %d milliseconds', [GetTickCount - a]));
end;
```

Comment: @Golez: Obviously I've got to slow it down. So what alternative methods are there to slow down the updating of the status bar?

Comment: @Golez: I'm running within a separate searching thread and have to synchronize the updates to the status bar, so that makes it slower for my program. Even so, if you were updating 10,000 times, it would take 10 seconds which is a big overhead.

Comment: I posted an alternative that is -unfortunately- integrated in the GUI, because I think it is a GUI thing to show the status and make this decisions. I only just read that you're using threads. This would mean that you still have to synchronize every update, still slowing you down. You can build this code in you thread too. It may not be the nicest solution, but referring to OwnerForm from a worker thread isn't the cleanest solution anyway. ;) At least it will boost performance *and* make the status readable to the user. Win win.

Comment: Golez: Actually, the idea of the FLastUpdate variable works great, even within my thread, and a simple call to MillisecondsBetween is really nice. That's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: For this type of update I often just use `if i mod 100 = 0 then UpdateStatus`

Comment: @Gerry: That will depend on the speed of your machine. As computers get faster, it will affect the amount of overhead performed. Checking for an interval of time (and I can pick the one I want) is better.

Comment: I ended up setting it to 50 ms, and it's way fast enough now and the status bar looks like its continuously updating.

Answer (score 4):

When you are running the search in a separate thread, you can simply update some variables with the NumFound and Total value. In the main thread you can fire a time every second (or whatever update interval you prefer) that reads this variables and updates the status bar.

As NumFound and Total probably are Integers, you can use the InterlockedXXX functions to update the variables in a simple but threadsafe way.

Comment: Good idea, but Golez's simple check works right in the thread, so I don't have to mess with synchronization.

Comment: @lkessler you already are messing with synchronisation. You bal synchronize. That has poor performance characteristics as you found. This method is the way I would always prefer to do it with no locks.

Comment: actually you don't even need the Interlocked routines so long as you align the integers on a 4 byte boundary. What you would have then is what is called a _benign_ race.